# What is not file in Linux

Tags: linux

When I first learned Linux, I was told **almost** everything in Linux is file. This morning, when I repeated it to my girlfriend. She asked what is not? I tried to find an example for half a day.

So my question is what is not file in Linux?

Comment: You may first like to define what a file is, here. Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file .

Comment: A process is not a file.

Comment: Access permissions are not files.

Comment: @lapk can't you reach them under `/proc/`?

Comment: Perhaps this question is a better fit at http://unix.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @Evert IMHO, `/proc` contains information about a process, but it's not a process itself.

Comment: I think the close votes are unwarrented. See my answer below.

Comment: I voted to reopen the question. I think this question is squarely about programming in Linux, and understanding the file descriptor interface, and the other interfaces used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost. Almost everything in Posix is handled through a file *descriptor*. This means that the same functions used for file operations also apply for pipes, sockets, and hardware devices. This also means that if you use `select` (or one of its better alternatives), you can have one point in your program where you wait for all possible inputs.

With that said, some things in Posix, and in particular, in Linux, are definitely not files.

The most obvious ones are signals. They are handled asynchronously to the program's execution, and therefor cannot take on a file interface. For that purpose, `pselect` and one of its better alternatives were invented.

Things more subtly not files are thread synchronization constructs (mutexs, semaphores, etc.). Some attempt have been made to make those available as file descriptors as well (see `signalfd` and `eventfd`), but those hardly caught on. I believe that this is due, in large part, for them having a vastly different performance profiles than the ususal way of handling them.

Answer (score 0):

for example computer hardware (CPU, RAM, Etc) is not actually a file, but it is represented as a file in linux.

[More details here](http://www.howtogeek.com/117939/htg-explains-what-everything-is-a-file-means-on-linux/)